# Android: Network calls don't work when i use network inspector

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to see all network calls in the monitor. Now  from all network calls(Retrofit) I get an error (exceptions) because of network inspector. This happened after updating Android Studio from Arctic Fox to BumbleBee. It works well on Arctic Fox. Who faced with such problems?

Comment: I've been having similar issues. Tried installing latest canary (Dolphin 7) and still have issues viewing Retrofit calls. Keep getting "There is no information for the
network traffic you've selected." even though Retrofit uses OkHttp. Hope someone can weigh in with a solution here.